# TypeError: can't convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first. 'trainer.fit' line

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

### The code below is what I'm trying to run.

```
early_stop_callback = EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", min_delta=1e-4, patience=5, verbose=True, mode="min")
lr_logger = LearningRateMonitor()  
logger = TensorBoardLogger("lightning_logs")  

trainer = pl.Trainer(
    max_epochs=45,
    accelerator='gpu', 
    devices=1,
    enable_model_summary=True,
    gradient_clip_val=0.1,
    callbacks=[lr_logger, early_stop_callback],
    logger=logger)

tft = TemporalFusionTransformer.from_dataset(
    training,
    learning_rate=0.001,
    hidden_size=160,
    attention_head_size=4,
    dropout=0.1,
    hidden_continuous_size=160,
    output_size=7,  # there are 7 quantiles by default: [0.02, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9, 0.98]
    loss=QuantileLoss(),
    log_interval=10, 
    reduce_on_plateau_patience=4)

trainer.fit(
    tft,
    train_dataloaders=train_dataloader,
    val_dataloaders=val_dataloader)`
```

As I have read on the internet, it require to change to cpu but I don't know how. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Please share a minimum working example and the entire error code for that example. Without that, it is difficult to troubleshoot.